# How to share cache including cookies between android.webkit.WebView(s)

Tags: java, android, caching, cookies, webview

My app has several different WebViews on different screens.  On one screen I would like to be able to sign in, saving a cookie with the user's customer information.  On another screen, I would like them to be able to remain signed in to view custom pricing, account info, etc.  This requires the two WebViews to share the same cookie.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Or even access the cookies?  Or use a common repository for web cache in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is kind of a silly problem.  The app I'm trying to extend is not sharing cookies between WebViews for some reason.  I assumed this was an issue with the Android SDK and not the app itself.  I coded up a simple example app with multiple WebViews and saw clearly that they were sharing cookies by default.  Now to figure out why or how the app I'm working on managed to circumvent sharing cookies between it WebViews.